# Bayes Stein Porfolio Implementation

Tags: covariance-matrix, covariance-estimation

From [this paper from Jorion](http://bfi.cl/papers/Jorion%201986%20-%20Bayes-Stein%20estimation%20for%20portfolio%20analysis.pdf).

Has anyone implemented this? How is the Covariance matrix estimated? It needs to estimate also the conditional distribution of the returns?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is explained in more detail in the Horse - Race of DeMiguel: [see here](http://faculty.london.edu/avmiguel/DeMiguel-Garlappi-Uppal-RFS.pdf)